# PHPUnit: How to test a class method that uses another static classes method

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have a class method I am trying to write a unit test for, it starts off something like this:

```
public function determineStatusActivity($proposal, $decisionStatusId): ?array
    {
        if (isset($proposal->contact_org_id)) {
            $this->personId = PipedriveActivityHelper::getPersonId($proposal->contact_org_id);
        }
```

I then have my test method which will need the response to run the check:

```
public function acceptedActivityTest()
{
    $activity = new CreateActivityInPipedriveForProposalStatusChange();
    $response = $activity->determineStatusActivity($this->proposal, 1);

    //Compare the response to a defined stub..
}
```

This class method `determineStatusActivity()` receives two pieces of data that I can create mocks for a pass to it, however I am at a loss at what to do when it gets to the static PipedriveActivityHelper class, is there a way to define the static class' behaviour in the test file method?

Comment: What does `PipedriveActivityHelper::getPersonId` do? Access a database? Contact an API? Something else that shouldn't be executed in the test?

Comment: In reality it access database info but should only return an integer id, i.e 3

Comment: Does it have any non-static methods?

Comment: No none at all, only static, if I can some how mock it and only return a single value without executing thatd be perfect.

Comment: Can the database setup itself be mocked? For instance, can you insert a `contact_org_id` that returns a valid `personId ` and then delete when done? Or is there more logic that gets fired, too?

Comment: It seems as though testing this method would have to be a part of an integration test, rather than a unit test. Or that helper shouldn't have static methods and should be inserted as a dependency which can in turn easily be replaced by a test double.

Comment: I just need somehow for the static method called in the method I am testing to return any number, doesnt even need to run

Comment: Without refactoring the code itself you can't affect the internal workings of `determineStatusActivity`. If you want to mock a static class, you have to find a way to get that mocked static class injected in, and your code doesn't have that accounted for. Adding DI might solve this, but it might introduce other problems if your code isn't ready for it, either. Basically, there isn't a quick fix.

Comment: Yeah exactly what I was thinking, its a really shit load of code that I have been asked to prep some tests for, wont be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [this](https://robertbasic.com/blog/mocking-hard-dependencies-with-mockery/) is what you are looking for, notice the test class decorators. TDD is always the best approach.